# SQL injection MariaDB python CTF

Tags: python, mariadb, sql-injection

I'm trying to get admin access to an app (ctf). The injection takes place in a login form in the username input. I can bypass the user but not the password (invalid username at first. After my injection, I get invalid password). I have some trouble understanding the python code related, especially the `.replace('%', '%%'))`.

Part of the error message :

```
if cursor.execute('SELECT password FROM users WHERE name=\'%s\'' % request.form['name'].replace('%', '%%')) == 0:
```

My payload is : `admin' union select 1;--`

Do you have any clues?

Comment: Don't use `%s`, use `?` and suitable syntax.

Comment: @RickJames Actually I can't modify it.  `if cur.execute('SELECT password FROM users WHERE name=\'%s\'' % request.form['name'].replace('%', '%%')) == 0:
` is in the error message or if you prefer the background request to the database. The injection takes place in the username field in the login form. Sorry, I haven't been clear enough.

Comment: Is this for testing or unauthorized access?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least escape backslash, apostrophe, and double quote.  For example, turning

```
admin' union select 1;--
```

into

```
admin\' union select 1;--
```

would have prevented *this* case of SQL injection.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. After a couple of hours of research I just used sqlmap...